# Order in Layer not working - Unity Hub 2021

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layer

I have been trying for some hours and almost finished reading all answers on Unity as well as on Stackoverflow. I still don't know how I can place that Pink Character shown in attached picture on to front of the Background. Can anyone please help me?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us1NT.png)

Comment: What's the object you want to put the pink character in front of?

Comment: @pixlhero It is safe to assume that he wants to put it over the canvas background.

Comment: Hmm.. that's a very weird strategy. @Am Salman, if that's the case, why not use a SpriteRenderer for the background? _Usually_ canvases are used for UI overlays.

Comment: @pixlhero I took a Canvas from than place the raw image on it and then took that sprite Pink Ninja character. And guess what the Ninja is not coming to front of that Background? Can you please guide me through every step. I am quite a beginner in it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about this, you just need to test out what works for you and be creative. There are a few things that you can do:

### Option - A

You can try to change Samus's Transform to a rect transform then set the z-index.

### Option - B

Change the canvas render mode or sort order

### Option - C

Add Samus to the canvas as an Image, then put the image above the background by moving it in the Hierarchy.

### Option - D

as suggested by @pixlhero, simply make the background image a SpriteRenderer as well then move it behind Samus in the Hierarchy.

Comment: I did try to change the Canvas Rendering from Screen-Space Overlay to World Space. And guess what it went to back BUT!!! when i run my game the screen was completely empty and not showing any of those two Objects ( Background and Character )

Comment: Sounds like you might need to rethink your entire layout. There are many great guides that will show you how to do it. The Unity.Learn website will be invaluable for you.

Comment: I think Option - D is the best way. it's also the intended way, because canvas is really more designed to be UI like buttons, text etc. You'll just run into more issues in the future otherwise.

Comment: I've never had any issues tossing everything onto the canvas, especially in 2D only. Also, the issue with sprite renderers disappearing is because they are not in front of the camera. Check their positions relative to the cameras and the camera settings.

Comment: What is Samus and where do I find it?

Comment: Samus Aron is a video game character which looks very similar to the character in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks everyone for your help.*

Here is how I solved the problem **without Code**

---

### Solution:

---

**Step 1**: Go to Hierarchy -> Create Empty GameObject.

**Step 2**: Click on Add Component to add a Sprite Renderer to your Empty GameObject.

**Step 3:** I imported my character by dragging it into Unity Project Asset Folder.

**Step 4:** Add the character into Hierarchy and then add Sprite Renderer Component to your Character.

Thanks,